# rspec controller spec matchers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller

With which matcher and how can I test if the `@post_comment` and `@post_comment.user` is properly assigned?

`expect(assigns(:post_comment)).to be_a_new(PostComment)` is not working here.

UPDATE:

With the following setup I also get the following error. What should I change to be able to test the invalid attrs?

```
Posts::PostCommentsController when user is logged in POST create with invalid attributes doesn't save the new product in the db
 Failure/Error: @post_comment.save!

 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: Body can't be blank
```

IF I delete `@post_comment.save!` then I get

```
Posts::PostCommentsController when user is logged in POST create with invalid attributes doesn't save the new product in the db
 Failure/Error: <span class="post-comment-updated"><%= local_time_ago(post_comment.updated_at) %></span>

 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `to_time' for nil:NilClass
```

post_comments_controller

```
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @post_comment = @post.post_comments.build(post_comment_params)
    authorize @post_comment
    @post_comment.user = current_user
    @post_comment.save!
    if @post_comment.save
      @post.send_post_comment_creation_notification(@post_comment)
      @post_comment_reply = PostCommentReply.new
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to posts_path, notice: "Comment saved!" }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

post_comments_controller_spec.rb

```
describe "POST create" do
  let!(:profile) { create(:profile, user: @user) }
  let!(:post_instance) { create(:post, user: @user) } 

  context "with valid attributes" do
    subject(:create_action) { xhr :post, :create, post_id: post_instance.id, post_comment: attributes_for(:post_comment, post_id: post_instance.id, user: @user) }

    it "saves the new task in the db" do
      expect{ create_action }.to change{ PostComment.count }.by(1)
    end

    it "assigns instance variables" do
      create_action
      expect(assigns(:post)).to eq(post_instance)
      #########How to test these two?
      #expect(assigns(:post_comment)).to be_a_new(PostComment)
      #expect(assigns(:post_comment.user)).to eq(@user)
      expect(assigns(:post_comment_reply)).to be_a_new(PostCommentReply)
    end

    it "assigns all the instance variables"

    it "responds with success" do
      create_action
      expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    end
  end

  context "with invalid attributes" do
    subject(:create_action) { xhr :post, :create, post_id: post_instance.id, post_comment: attributes_for(:post_comment, post_id: post_instance.id, user: @user, body: "") }

    it "doesn't save the new product in the db" do
      expect{ create_action }.to_not change{ PostComment.count }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: "to be a new" is awaiting for a new unsaved record

Comment: `@post_comment = @post.post_comments.build(post_comment_params)` is not saved.

Comment: I found another problem in the meantime. I also inserted that one.

Comment: How can I solve this? If I delete the `@post_comment.save!` then I get another type of error. I also added that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. How to test these two?

   ```
   expect(assigns(:post_comment)).to be_a_new(PostComment)
   expect(assigns(:post_comment.user)).to eq(@user)
   ```

   I believe you shoudl test not a new record, but a record of a class, and persisted record:

   ```
   expect(assigns(:post_comment)).to be_a(PostComment)
   expect(assigns(:post_comment)).to be_presisted
   expect(assigns(:post_comment.user)).to eq(@user)
   ```
2. Excessive code.

   ```
   @post_comment.save!
   if @post_comment.save
   ```

   You shall to keep only the single record of that, I believe it is enough save with exception:

   ```
   @post_comment.save!
   ```

   So other part code you can pick out of `if` block. Exception from `save!` you shall to trap with `rescue_from`.

Comment: I tried both way `@post_comment.save!` and `if @post_comment.save`, but both of these will send some kind of error. If I keep the `@post_comment.save!` then I get the first error I listed, if I keep the `if` version then I got the other error message.

Comment: @SzilardMagyar That is good, `save!` method tell you that you didn't fill in the body attribute, see your model validation

Comment: What I don't get is that why throws the test this error. I also tested "with invalid attributes" similar way in other controllers and the test just passed as it also should here.

Comment: @SzilardMagyar but if you omit the body attr, they will become invalid

Comment: But that's the point. I leave the body empty so `expect{ create_action }.to_not change{ PostComment.count }` will pass, since it doesn't get saved in the db.

Comment: @SzilardMagyar either trap error in test, but I advice to trap error in controller with `rescue_from`

Comment: Can you tell me why it's happening? I don't see this controller being different from the rest that working.

Comment: @SzilardMagyar what is happening exactly?

Comment: So I'm confused. You were right it maybe to excessive with the `bang` and `if` version together. I tried to delete the bang line. With doing that as I see all my controllers are similar (I mostly use the `if @object.save`), still here I get `ActionView::Template::Error:`

Comment: @SzilardMagyar you should render an error template in case of exception/false return.

Comment: I create a new question for that and link here. I also have a post controller and just can't see the difference.

Comment: @SzilardMagyar where is the link?

Comment: Just a sec, assembling the question at this very moment

Comment: Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36925750/rspec-controller-specs-testing-post-action