# rspec controller specs testing post action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller

For some reason the `post spec` working fine but the `post_comment_spec` test fails. Post has many post_comments, post_comment belongs to post.

error:

```
1) Posts::PostCommentsController when user is logged in POST create with invalid attributes doesn't save the new product in the db
 Failure/Error: <span class="post-comment-updated"><%= local_time_ago(post_comment.updated_at) %></span>

 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `to_time' for nil:NilClass
```

posts_controller

```
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)
  authorize @post
  if @post.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

post_comments_controller

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @post_comment = @post.post_comments.build(post_comment_params)
  authorize @post_comment
  @post_comment.user = current_user
  #@post_comment.save!
  if @post_comment.save
    @post.send_post_comment_creation_notification(@post_comment)
    @post_comment_reply = PostCommentReply.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

posts_controller_spec.rb

```
describe "POST create" do
  let!(:profile) { create(:profile, user: @user) }

  context "with invalid attributes" do
    subject(:create_action) { xhr :post, :create, post: attributes_for(:post, user: @user, body: "") }

    it "doesn't save the new product in the db" do
      expect{ create_action }.to_not change{ Post.count }
    end
  end
end
```

post_comments_controller_spec.rb

```
describe "POST create" do
  let!(:profile) { create(:profile, user: @user) }
  let!(:post_instance) { create(:post, user: @user) }

  context "with invalid attributes" do
    subject(:create_action) { xhr :post, :create, post_id: post_instance.id, post_comment: attributes_for(:post_comment, post_id: post_instance.id, user: @user, body: "") }

    it "doesn't save the new product in the db" do
      expect{ create_action }.to_not change{ PostComment.count }
    end
  end
end
```

create.js.erb for post

```
$("ul.errors").html("");
<% if @post.errors.any? %>
  $('.alert-danger').show();
  $('ul.errors').show();
  <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    $("ul.errors").append($("<li />").html("<%= message.html_safe %>"));
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  $('ul.errors').hide();
  $('.alert-danger').hide();
  $('.post-index').prepend('<%= j render @post %>');
  collectionPostEditDropdown();
  $('.post-create-body').val('');
  $('#img-prev').attr('src', "#");
  $('#img-prev').addClass('hidden');
  $('.btn-create-post').prop('disabled',true);
  $('.remove-post-preview').addClass('hidden');
<% end %>
```

create.js.erb for post_comment

```
<% unless @post_comment.errors.any? %>
  $("#post-comment-text-area-<%= @post_comment.post_id%>").val('');
  $(".post-comment-insert-<%= @post_comment.post_id %>").prepend('<%= j render @post_comment %>');
  $(".best_in_place").best_in_place();
<% end %>
```

Comment: Neven, I don't really get your question.

Comment: `post_comment` isn't saved, so `updated_at` is nil

Comment: How can I test it then? I mean the code is fine, since it only will be rendered if properly saved.

Comment: What behavior are you expecting when trying to create a blank comment? `create.js.erb` expects that `@post_comment` is valid...

Comment: I dont see the code is fine, do `render js` with errors,  to see it in test, but if it passes  valid attributes, why it is erroneous?

Comment: @SzilardMagyar fill in the body!

Comment: I put `<% unless @post_comment.errors.any? %>` block around the code in the create.js.erb and now it's working fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, the call to `local_time_ago` ends up trying to call `to_time` on nil - so your comment doesn't have anything in its `updated_at` attribute.

In **post_comments_controller.rb**, why did you comment out `#@post_comment.save!`?

And what is `@post_comment.save` returning? I suspect the save is failing for some reason, but you're still trying to render `create.js.erb` which is expecting a valid `@post_comment` object.

EDIT: You shouldn't be rendering `create.js.erb` when `@post_comment.save` fails, since it's expecting a valid `@post_comment` object. You probably want to `render json: nil, status: :ok` in that case.

Comment: Brian here is the original issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36924449/rspec-controller-spec-matchers/36925108?noredirect=1#comment61412428_36925108 I commented out because if I use `@post_comment.save!` too, it sends validation error in the test which is superweird. Btw what I don't understand is why I put there originally since the code is working properly as it is now. There is only problem with the test.

Comment: The validation error is the problem here - since the `save` is failing, you're trying to render `create.js.erb` with an unpersisted object. What was the validation error?

Comment: Updated the question. `Body can't be blank` was the error, which is okay since I pass `body: ""` in the test.

Comment: So you must have `validate :body, presence: true` in your `post_comment` model, and since you're passing in "", the validation is failing. The validation failure is causing `@post_comment.save` to return false, and then `@post_comment` is not a valid object, so trying to access it from `create.js.erb` isn't working.

Comment: Brian, why is it working with post and not with post_comment?

Comment: I guess the `create.js.erb` for posts isn't attempting to render @post - is it rendering the `<% if @post.errors.any? %>` branch?

Comment: That's the problem! Unfortunately 10 mins ago I wrote `<%= unless @post_comment.errors.any? %>` with equal sign in it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Brian, you also mentioned I should use `head no content` with json response in case of error for js request. Why is that good in general?

Comment: No need for that now that you have logic in your js file.